# Generic Pub / Sub; To and from JSON

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am interested in subscribing to a set of topics, receiving messages and sending messages to topics. I have a generic subscription as `void cb_generic(const std::string& _msg)`. The content of the string is protobuf binary message which I want to convert to JSON. Any suggestions or examples on how to accomplish this task? The steps I see are:

1. Convert std::string to protobuf object
2. Convert protobuf object to json.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21467/generic-pub-/-sub;-to-and-from-json/) by [prakash](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7618/prakash/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The first step would require deserialization of the binary message into a protobuf structure. Then you could translate the deserialized message into json. There might be libraries that can do the conversion for you. I think protobuf3 has support for json, but I haven't used that capability yet.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2018-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prakash](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7618/prakash/) on 2019-01-18**:
Thank you for taking the time to respond.